# How can I send form values from jsp file to controller in Spring, JSP?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to design a web page allows users to make comments on eachothers' profiles. To do this, the logged in user clicks the name of another user and see his/her detailed profile page and can make comment on that page. So the *Comment* table has two foreign key columns as *commentator_id* and *owner_id*. When a user makes a comment on another user's profile, the comment table will keep the both users' id and the text, title of comment and so on.

Here's my *Controller* :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/comment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView comment(Principal principal, String username, @ModelAttribute Comment c) {

        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("result");

        User user = userService.findByUsername(username); // the user who gets the comment

        String username2 = (String) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal(); //logged in user who makes the comment
        User authenticatedUser = userService.findByUsername(username2);


        c.setCommentator(authenticatedUser);;
        c.setOwner(user);


        user.getComments().add(c);

        userService.save(host);

        String message = "Com was successfully added.";
        result.addObject("message", message);
        return result;

    }
```

My *jsp* file :

```
<body>
  <form method="post" action="comment">
            <center>
            <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Leave a referance</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td>Title</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="title" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Text</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="message" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>

       // ...

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
             <a href="<c:url value="/comment"><c:param name="username" value="${user.getUsername()}"/></c:url>">Send</a>
                      </form>
</body>
```

With this way, a user can make comment on another user's profile but the *Comment* table only keeps the id of both user but not the text, title and other values which I get from the form. How can I also keep form values in the db?

Comment: Are you using Spring MVC right way? Why not using Spring form along with a command object and other Spring elements?

Comment: What do u mean by _along with a command object and other Spring elements_ how can I do in different way?

Answer (score 0):

use ModelAttribute annotation

```
   public ModelAndView getMessage(@ModelAttribute("s") Student s){
       ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("Successpage");
     return model;
   }
```